How to increase interword spacing
I am using a font:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext}

and I find the words simply too close together constantly,
how can I increase the spacing?
I tried  \SetExtraSpacing [ unit = space ] % default { font = */*/*/*/* } { space = {5000,5000,5000}, } \begin{document} and it does not work.
And I tried  \fontdimen2\font=3pt% but it simply isn't refined enough for me. At 3 its too crammed, and at 4 its too much, and it won't accept decimal values.
Essentially the big issue is I run into situations like this.


Please provide your MWE as in executable format

look at microtype.

This code compiles without problem. What do you mean setting \fontdimen2 only takes integer (non-decimal) pts?

I did look at microtype but could not get it working. Werner's code seems to have done it, thanks. I meant that it was being weird when trying to use different point numbers, like it would only change at certain multiples or not at all, for example like 3.15 and 3 are the same

If you are using T1 fontencoding, soul.sty will helps you

you can use any tex dimension for \fontdimen so about 5 decimal places of pt

@xyz04 3.15pt is 0.15pt longer than 3pt so the target width is larger but in code (which for some reason you have not shown) you are presumably using justified text so the stretch and shrink components will play a part, if tex decides to make the line break at the same point then the shrink component will stretch to compensate for the larger natural width, leading to the same space in the document but considered with greater badness as tex had to shrink the space more to achieve that line break.

In the title of your query, you ask how to shrink interword spacing, yet in the body of the query you ask "how can I increase the spacing" [emphasis added]. Please clarify your goal. A separate question: Are you using the euler or eulervm math font package? E.g., something like \usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}? Please confirm. Finally, please edit your posting to show the entire sentence or parapraph that contains the code snippet we find that $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(n)=$. Thanks.

\sloppy will increase the spacing, but by a variable amount.  Also, $...$ generally adds esta space around math expressions.  You mist be doing something special to avoid it.

I am using the eulervm for my math.

Don't tell only in a comment, what you are using. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. Reproducibility of the problem is the first step to an answerable question and thus to a solution.
